# Need help identifying old house interior wall panel

Tags: walls, interior, old-house

I'm fixing a hole in a wall that is made of a material I cannot identify and therefore locate.  House was built circa 1940.  I believe the wall was exterior before an addition.  The material is approximately 7/8" thick and consists of two layers.  The inward facing layer is some kind of cement.  It is laminated perfectly onto the stud facing side which is definitely drywall.

I'm having trouble replacing the piece I cut out mostly because of the unusual thickness.  All my ideas on how to search and identify this material has come up with nothing.  Any idea what this stuff is and if I can even get it any more?[image]

Comment: Quite a few building materials between 1940s and now have shrunk.  Problem with 1940s is that they were using asbestos, so protective gear is needed if fooling around(cutting, sanding) with it, or have it tested to be sure.

Comment: The drywall-like stuff is most likely ["rock lath"](https://misspreservation.com/2012/04/19/the-real-rock-lath-of-jackson-county/).

Comment: Making the room-facing "cement-like stuff" plaster. Write up an answer, @HotLicks

Comment: Depending on location, that might be button board with a ton of plaster. Anyway, the fix is to get the patch close to the surface level and then fill the void. (Setting compound is good for filling, as it sets fast and shrinks less than AP.)